# Relative URLs within sub application on IIS site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7.5

I have "test" website on IIS and "sub1" sub-application within it.

When I request domain.com/sub1, IIS processes sub-application sucessfully.

Some of URLs in code are relative, and when I have something like this in code /component/test, application requests following url domain.com/component/test instead of domain.com/sub1/component/test.

What do I need to change in order to make relative URLs to be valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code, use `@Url.Content("~/")` or `<% =Url.Content("~/") %>` to get to the relative root of the application.

Or, sometimes, you can get away with prefixing with `~/`, but generally only with js and css files in your layout

note: the `@` is for razor view engine, and the `<% %>` is for aspx view engine, you didn't specify which you were using

**EDIT:** (based on comment from OP)

CSS should be relative from the directory your CSS is hosted, you can use `../` to traverse directories. For your JS, can you edit those files? I would define a SITE_ROOT variable (above all js files) in your layout and then reference that variable from within your JS files

example: `var SITE_ROOT = '@Url.Content("~/")';`

then prefix your calls in the JS file with `SITE_ROOT + '/relative_url'`

Comment: These issues are from JS/CSS files. POST url is hard-coded in JS. All URLs start with "/"